# Wiener filter: A good tutorial

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am interested in image analysis and am looking for an approachable tutorial to the Wiener filter. At some point I am interested in implementing such a filter but I would like to have a deeper understanding of the algorithms I'll be writing. Does anyone have recommendations for papers, web sites, etc. that present good coverage on the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detection Estimation and Modulation Theroy Volume 1 by Harry Van Trees is a good start if you have a basic understanding of Probability and Random Variables.  Any statistical signal processing book should also cover Wiener Filtering